# Stop Execution for Multiple Files - Python

Tags: python, windows, if-statement, automation, operating-system

I am attempting to stop the execution of a script (run_all.py) via the Windows Terminal that runs multiple files contained within a list, based on specific conditions being met in each file.  Specifically, in file_2.py I want to pause the execution of that file based on the value of the "y" parameter and subsequently halt execution of any files that have yet to be run in the file list (i.e. file_3.py).  I am currently using the time module to pause file_2.py for 60 seconds, but I need a more elegant way to stop the execution without the need for a manual keyboard command (e.g. Ctrl + C)...any assistance is most appreciated!

file_1.py

```
print("Math is fun!")
```

file_2.py

```
import os
import time

x=1
y=2

if x < 10:
   print("x is small")
else:
   print("x is invalid")
if y < 10:
   print("y is also small")
else:
   print('press "ctrl + c" to stop execution of the workflow')
   time.sleep(60)
```

file_3.py

```
print("python is so cool!")
```

run_all.py (main script run from the Windows terminal)

```
import os
path = "C:\\users\\mdl518\\Desktop\\"

file_list = ['file_1.py', 'file_2.py', 'file_3.py']

for filename in file_list:
    os.system('python' + ' ' + os.path.join(path,filename)) # runs all files in the file_list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the condition is in one of the other files (like in your case), raise a `ValueError`.  For example:

```py
x = 2
y = 9

if x < 10:
    raise ValueError("x is small")
if y < 10:
   raise ValueError("y is small")
```

It would be a better practice to turn your code in these files into functions and import the functions inside the `run_all` file instead of calling python to run them as separate processes. For example:

file 1 (f1.py):

```py
def f1():
    print("Math is fun!")
```

file 2 (f2.py):

```py
def f2(x, y):
    if x < 10:
        raise ValueError("y is small")
    if y < 10:
       raise ValueError("y is small")
```

file 3 (f3.py):

```py
def f3():
    print("python is so cool!")
```

run_all file:

```
from f1 import f1
from f2 import f2
from f3 import f3

funs = [f1(), f2(1, 2), f3()]

for f in funs:
    f
```

Comment: Thanks, @feline, your proposed solution makes sense! The "break" statement breaks out of a For loop, not an If statement.  I'll tweak my original post with your edit, and confirm your answer as the correct solution - Thanks again!